# Is this example causing an undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, language-lawyer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

The variable `i` is changed twice, but is the next example going to cause an undefined behaviour?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    std::cout << "before i=" << i << std::endl;
    ++ i %= 4;
    std::cout << "after i=" << i << std::endl;
}
```

The output I get is :

```
before i=5
after i=2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's undefined. There is no sequence point on assignment, % or ++ And you cannot change a variable more than once within a sequence point.

A compiler could evaluate this as:

```
++i;
i = i % 4;
```

or

```
i = i % 4;
++i;
```

(or something else)